# Problem with corrupt .rar file

Tags: macos, finder, compression, rar

I have a big file compressed in split `.rar` archives. There are 68 archives named .rar, .r01, .r02, etc., annd the problem is that `.r36` is corrupted resulting in an `Unexpected end of archive`. I've looked around and I have found nothing.

There is no way to repair the file.

And now my question is if it's possible to *skip* the file. I mean, extract all files except the `.r36`. The result should be a big file with a small part of it corrupted, but it doesn't matter.

Is that possible - to *skip* a file from extraction? Because my main problem is that all the apps I've tried stop the task when they find the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your archive comes with recovery files(.rev) you can regenerate missing or broken parts.

I use command line version of [rar](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11159/rar) for this.
Just execute this command: `rar e archive-name.r01`. This will extract from all the parts and rebuild the broken ones.

Instead if you don't have rev files you can't do nothing. You can't just skip.

Comment: That was my conclusion some time ago. I mark your answer as correct ;)